# Update application which is already in google play

Tags: android

I can't find this information and I already start my journey with android. I have a question to you. If I create application and add to google play, can I upgrade this same application after some time. For example. I add application to google play and after 1 month I want to add the same application with some new functions. This is possible?

Comment: http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-update-your-app-in-google-play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes
just change the versionCode it the AndroidManifest.xml file
keep the same package and sign with the same keys

then go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/ and upload the new version

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Just sign the APK with the same keystore, and maintain the package name between versions.